# How can I add a line item to sublist via beforeSubmit event?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm creating a `beforeSubmit` script that needs to add a new line item to a sublist and commit both.

I've tried use `selectLine`, `insertLine` and `selectNewLineItem`, but no one worked adding the line during the record save:

```
record.insertLine({
sublistId: "item",
line: 1
});

record.setCurrentSublistValue({
sublistId: 'item',
fieldId: 'item',
value: 3919,
ignoreFieldChange: true,
forceSyncSourcing: true,
fireSlavingSync: true
});

record.setCurrentSublistValue({
sublistId: 'item',
fieldId: 'quantity',
value: 1,
fireSlavingSync: true
});

record.setCurrentSublistValue({
sublistId: 'item',
fieldId: 'amount',
value: valorProd1,
ignoreFieldChange: true,
forceSyncSourcing: true,
fireSlavingSync: true
});

record.commitLine({
sublistId: 'item'
});
```

Any are appreciated!

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertLine` only inserts line and does not selects it, whereas to use `setCurrentSublistValue` you need to select the line first. So replacing `insertLine` with `selectNewLine` should do the trick for you.

You can check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273170152.html) out for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i still get an error... something like this: " Cannot find function selectNewLine in object standard record."
That's my record declaration:  record = context.newRecord;

Comment: Could you check if your record is in dynamic mode? To check is record in in dynamic mode, use `nsRecord.isDynamic`. If your record is not in dynamic mode you cannot use `selectLine` or `setCurrentSublistValue` and you will have to use `setSublistValue` in conjunction with `insertLine`.